# How to define jenkins build trigger in jenkinsfile to start build after other job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, build-triggers

I would like to define a build trigger in my `Jenkinsfile`. I know how to do it for the BuildDiscarderProperty:

```
properties([[$class: 'jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', numToKeepStr: '50', artifactNumToKeepStr: '20']]])
```

How can I set the Build Trigger that starts the job, when another project has been built. I cannot find a suitable entry in the [Java API docs](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/package-summary.html).

Edit:
My solution is to use the following code:

```
stage('Build Agent'){
  if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop') {
    try {
        // try to start subsequent job, but don't wait for it to finish
        build job: '../Agent/develop', wait: false
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        echo "An error occurred while building the agent."
    }
  }
  if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
    // start subsequent job and wait for it to finish
    build '../Agent/master', wait: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I just looked for the same thing and found this `Jenkinsfile`[in jenkins-infra/jenkins.io](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/blob/c0828af5b8bd428815e23537c808cd0267017013/Jenkinsfile#L6)

In short:

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([cron('H/30 * * * *')])
])
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is an example:**

```
#Project test1
pipeline {
  agent {
    any
  }
    stages {
      stage('hello') {
        steps {
            container('dind') {
              sh """
                  echo "Hello world!"
              """
          }
        }
      }
    }
    post {
      success{
        build propagate: false, job: 'test2'
      }
    }
  }
```

**post {}** will be execute when project test1 is built and the code inside

**success {}** will only be executed when project test1 is successful.

**build propagate: false, job: 'test2'** will call project test2.

**propogate: false** ensures that project test1 does not wait for project test2's
completion and simply invokes it.